# How to simplify a list of if statements that paste strings together in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to write a function to interact with the YouTube Analytics API. There are 11 arguments that could potentially be used, with 4 of them being required. I wrote a couple of if statements to check that `startDate`, `endDate`, and `metrics` aren't null, but after that I have a list of if statements saying that if one of the other arguments is not null then append it to the baseUrl, as seen below.

```
# Arguments
currency = NULL
dimensions = NULL
endDate = NULL,
filters = NULL
ids = "channel==MINE"
includeHistoricalChannelData = NULL
maxResults = NULL
metrics = NULL
sort = NULL,
startDate = NULL
startIndex = NULL

# Check that start date, end date, and metrics aren't null
if(is.null(startDate) | is.null(endDate)) {
  stop("Please provide start/end dates")
}
if(is.null(metrics)) {
  stop("Please provide valid metrics")
}

baseUrl <- paste0("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?",
                    "&ids=", ids
                    "&startDate=", startDate,
                    "&endDate=", endDate)

 # Append additional arguments to baseUrl
  if (!is.null(dimensions)){ baseUrl <- paste0(baseUrl, "&dimensions=", dimensions)}
  if (!is.null(metrics)){    baseUrl <- paste0(baseUrl, "&metrics=", metrics)}
  if (!is.null(sort)){       baseUrl <- paste0(baseUrl, "&sort=", sort)}
  if (!is.null(maxResults)){ baseUrl <- paste0(baseUrl, "&maxResults=", maxResults)}
  if (!is.null(filters)){    baseUrl <- paste0(baseUrl, "&filters=", filters)}
```

This method works, but gets long to write. I wanted to know if there is a simpler way to write this list of if statements?

Comment: consider either  `if ... else if ...`  or better yet, using  `switch`

Comment: This is the method to go. You just need to wrap that in a function

Comment: @CarlWitthoft what would a switch statement look like?

Comment: No need of a switch statement. You will be complicating your life. Also, switch works with equality and not with NULLs. You can reduce the number of lines but that will be just complicating things. Though verbouse, your code above is pretty straightforward and easy to follow. Maintain that. Unless you want to write a shorter complex code with your own class.

Comment: @Onyambu you are incorrect:  `switch` works with any *statement* that evaluates to TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @Jacob  you could start by reading `?switch`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  equality also returns TRUE, FALSE. Note that you cannot use switch for inequalities. Please take your time to look at switch again. Your statement that I am incorrect is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing I found was to put all the variables into a list, then to filter out `NULL` values, which looks like the following:

```
myList <- list(currency = NULL,
               dimensions = NULL,
               endDate = NULL,
               filters = NULL,
               ids = "channel==MINE",
               includeHistoricalChannelData = NULL,
               maxResults = NULL,
               metrics = NULL,
               sort = NULL,
               startDate = NULL,
               startIndex = NULL)

newList <- Filter(Negate(is.null), myList)
```

Then I can paste all values together doing the following:

```
params <- paste0("&", names(newList), "=", unlist(newList), collapse = "")

url <- paste0("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the many if statements, you can create a class and create a method for this particular class that will be called. Although as stated in my comments above, I would prefer to maintain your code as is currently is.

```
# define the class. 
my_class <- function(x)  structure(x, class = "my_class")

# Define `+` method for this class
"+.my_class" <- function(e1, e2){
  if(is.null(e2)) return(e1)
  my_class(paste0(e1, '&', substitute(e2), '=', e2))
}



# Arguments
currency = NULL
dimensions = NULL
endDate = as.character(today() + 1)
filters = NULL
ids = "channel==MINE"
includeHistoricalChannelData = NULL
maxResults = NULL
metrics = 'accuracy'
sort = NULL
startDate = as.character(today())
startIndex = NULL

# Check that start date, end date, and metrics aren't null
if(is.null(startDate) | is.null(endDate)) {
  stop("Please provide start/end dates")
}
if(is.null(metrics)) {
  stop("Please provide valid metrics")
}
```

--

Now call:

```
c(my_class("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?") +
  ids + startDate + endDate +  dimensions + metrics + sort +
  maxResults + filters)

[1] "https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?&ids=channel==MINE&startDate=2023-07-07&endDate=2023-07-08&metrics=accuracy"
```